# How can i set segment in image color for ios?

Tags: ios, swift, segment

I need to set a black color image in segment 0 ...
but the color always follows tint color...
like this
[image]

[image]

How to set segment image color?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I just need set a image on segment ,but display color is tint's color

Comment: Do you mean that you have a single image, and that you want to put another image on top of it? Do you have an array of images? I would like to help, but I don't understand your question. Can you show the code that displays what you have so far?

Comment: sorry ，my english is very poor... I need display a black image...but now display a white image,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your original folder image, call `imageWithRenderingMode:` with a rendering mode of `. AlwaysOriginal`. Now the image will be used exactly as is, with no tinting.

Comment: sorry ,I am a rookie.Can you speak another elaborate?

Comment: No, I'm not going to write your code for you. I've told you _exactly_ what to do. You read the docs. You write the code.